# Call/Reference JavaScript Method/Function using/assigning Variable

Tags: javascript

Here is what I want to achieve-

```
document.write('Something'); 
var d = document; // So that i need not to repeat document everytime
d.write('SomethingElse'); //Working
var w = write(); // or w = write
d.w("Something"); //Not Working
```

document.w; //Something Like This is Not Working either
    document.w("Something"); //This is too Not Working

Why this is not working? I have searched to find a way to achieve like this. Referencing method of a function?
I have working JS code but for minifying I want to do this.

**UPDATE**
Original Code

**Minified Working**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function t() {
        var t = this,
            a = moment,
            e = $(".scheduleTimeZone option:selected"),
            d = $("[data-current-timezone]", t),
            m = $("[data-start-date]", t),
            n = $("[data-start-time]", t),
            o = $("[data-end-date]", t),
            r = $("[data-end-time]", t),
            i = d.data("currenttimezone"),
            c = e.val(),
            h = "MMMM DD, YYYY",
            f = "hh:mm A",
            u = h + " " + f,
            l = m.data("start-date") + " " + n.data("start-time"),
            s = a.tz(l, u, i).utc().format(),
            z = a(s).tz(c),
            M = o.data("end-date") + " " + r.data("end-time"),
            Y = a.tz(M, u, i).utc().format(),
            p = a(Y).tz(c);
        m.html(z.format(h)), n.html(z.format(f)), o.html(p.format(h)), r.html(p.format(f))
    }
    $(".scheduleTimeZone").change(function() {
        $(".profile-stat[data-datetime]").each(t)
    })
});
```

**I want to replace format with mf**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function t() {
        var t = this,
            a = moment,
            mf = format,
            e = $(".scheduleTimeZone option:selected"),
            d = $("[data-current-timezone]", t),
            m = $("[data-start-date]", t),
            n = $("[data-start-time]", t),
            o = $("[data-end-date]", t),
            r = $("[data-end-time]", t),
            i = d.data("currenttimezone"),
            c = e.val(),
            h = "MMMM DD, YYYY",
            f = "hh:mm A",
            u = h + " " + f,
            l = m.data("start-date") + " " + n.data("start-time"),
            s = a.tz(l, u, i).utc().af(),
            z = a(s).tz(c),
            M = o.data("end-date") + " " + r.data("end-time"),
            Y = a.tz(M, u, i).utc().af(),
            p = a(Y).tz(c);
        m.html(z.af(h)), n.html(z.af(f)), o.html(p.af(h)), r.html(p.format(f))
    }
    $(".scheduleTimeZone").change(function() {
        $(".profile-stat[data-datetime]").each(t)
    })
});
```

How can I skip the repetition???

Comment: Document is a reference, write is a function.

Comment: I know @Reisclef. Is there any way to do like this? I do not want to repeat the function of a reference.

Comment: Don't minify your own code. There are plenty of free tools that will do a better job than you will.

Comment: @Mahi That is not working either.

Comment: @lonesomeday You are right but the level of minification depends on our coding.

Comment: better to use minify library

Comment: I have no problem with minification. I just want to know that how can I reference a method/function like referencing a reference.

Comment: `var w = document.write`